# How to get the actual value from a Silverlight combobox instead of DTO values

Tags: silverlight

I am automating a silverlight application for testing.
I have a Silverlight combobox that has 1000s of values.

I am able to select the values by index but not by passing the actual values.

Also, if I try to get the content of the combobox, it displays in the form of data template objects some xyz.DTOs.

I do not have development knowledge, so I am unable to understand the datatemplate concept and decode it.

Can someone help me to understand how to retrieve the actual value from the combobox instead of the code or how to select the value by passing the values instead of the index.

Appreciate if someone can provide quick suggestions.

Thanks,
SlvAutomator

Comment: See if *SelectedText* property works for you.

Comment: _SelectedText_ is part of the System.Windows.Forms namespace (WinForms), therefore it is not a property for the Silverlight ComboBox

Answer (score 1):

You can select the **Content** property of the combo box item by doing something like this:

```
     string content = ((ComboBoxItem)comboBox.Items[index]).Content.ToString();
```

To select a item by using the Content property, you need to specify the **SelectedValuePath** in the combobox:

```
   <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" Width="100" Height="100" SelectedValuePath="Content">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Blue"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Black" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Dark Red" />
    </ComboBox>
```

Then in the code behind you can select a value like this:

```
    comboBox.SelectedValue = "Black";
```